# SharePoint 2010 central administration site error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, assemblies, admin, gac

I have just come to revisit an old virtual sharepoint 2010 install. When I crank up central administration I get the following error:

```
The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131018)

Line 379:    <compilation batch="false" debug="false">
Line 380:      <assemblies>
Line 381:        <add assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
```

I have looked in the GAC and the assemblies are there.

I have ran the central administration configuration wizard through to see if this repaired the issue.

Can anyone suggest and an approach to resolving this?

all the best

Comment: Where are you seeing this? I'm confused by your posting because I don't see how you were able to run the central admin wizard when central admin is erroring out.

Comment: I am referring to when I select central admin in the start menu and it loads up the central admin website in the browser. The central admin config wizard is a separate option in the start menu unrelated to actually running the website. I am seeing the error when I attempt to load the central admin website.

Answer (score 0):

Right, I think it was an application pool setting that was the issue. The central admin app pool was set to framework version 2.0 - I have changed it to 4.0 and am now past this error.

I think this is the cause of the issue but would appreciate anyone's views on this.

Comment: I believe this may have been a red herring, there does in fact appear to be a cumilative update relating to machines running the framework 4.0 and sharepoint http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2536599